# Fasting and Period in Ramadan

Tags: sawm

It is ramadan and yesterday, i was not sure if my period ended yet. So, I thought today i was not going to fast because i was not certain that it had ended. 
When i woke up today after fajr, i did not intend to fast but i soon realized that, in fact, it did end. And it would have ended before fajr. At that point, it was well before dhuhr and i had not eaten or drank anything so, i fasted this whole day.

Is my fast valid? Do i still have to make it up?

Answer (score 1):

It is essential to have intention to fast **before Fajr** in order for your fast to be valid. As you did not intend to fast, your fast is not valid. See [Is fast valid without niyyat?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/15055/is-fast-valid-without-niyyat).

You should make this up.

Answer (score -1):

The intention (niyyat) for fasting you can have before noon (Duhar) time. But specific to your situation some part of time your may be in state of menstruation so, because of this your fasting will not be valid. Otherwise it could be valid.

For example, suppose you're not feeling well before sleeping and doubtful intention about fasting next day (depending on how you'll be feeling) and then you woke up late in the morning and found yourself feeling better then you can have fasting intnetion and can continue.