# should i keep fasting if i didn’t make intention

Tags: sawm, ramadan, niyyah

i used to make intention to fast everyday of ramadan but today i forgot to make the intention but i’m unsure if my fast is valid or not’ but i did make intention to fast for everyday of ramadan starting on the 10th (i said this on the first too but broke my fast on the third)is my fast valid because i thought in my head “i am intending to fast everyday of ramadan starting now”on the 10th day of ramadan

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/15055/is-fast-valid-without-niyyat. This should answer your question

Comment: not really as i didn’t wake up for suhoor and i don’t know if i made intention in my heart but on the 10th i said i’d fast everyday left of ramadan does that count?

Answer (score 0):

I can’t leave comments yet. I’m not too sure then because I know waking up for suhoor isn’t a must for your fast to be valid but it’s the intention thing that’s confusing me. Maybe someone else can asnwer this better than me, sorry.